# Regex find most center

Tags: regex

I need to manully hyphante words that are too long. Using hyphen.js, I get soft hyphens between every syllable, like below.

I want to find the hyphen closes to the middle. All words will be more than 14 characters long. Regex that works in https://regex101.com/ or node/js example.

Basically, find the middle character excluding hyphens, check if there is a hyphen there, then step backwards one step and then forwards one step, then backwards to steps etc.

```
re-spon-si-bil-i-ties => [re-spon-si,-bil-i-ties]
com-pe-ten-cies. => [com-pe,-ten-cies.]
ini-tia-tives. => [ini-tia,-tives]
vul-ner-a-bil-i-ties => [vul-ner-a,-bil-i-ties]
```

Comment: Define middle please.  Is it the one that is the middle of the word, or for example the 2nd hyphen in a word with 3 hyphens?  What is the middle if the word has an odd number of letters, or if there is an even number of hyphens?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: `vul-ner-a-bil-i-ties` - what is the "middle" here?

Comment: @RobertMcKee sorry, will update question

Comment: @esqew, I have no idea how to do this in a good way. Maybe some kind of for-loop through the letters, middle out

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with:

```js
var words = [
    're-spon-si-bil-i-ties',
    'com-pe-ten-cies.',
    'ini-tia-tives.',
    'vul-ner-a-bil-i-ties',
    're-ports—typ-i-cal-ly',
    'none'
];

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i){
    var matches = words[i]
                    .match(
                        new RegExp(
                            '^((?:[^-]+?-?){' // Start the regex
                            +parseInt(
                                words[i].replace( /-/g, '' ).length/2 // Round down the halfway point of this word's length without the hyphens
                            )
                            +'})(-.+)?$' // End the regex
                        )
                    )
                    .slice( 1 ); // Remove position 0 because it is the entire word
    console.log( matches );
}
```

Regex explanation for `re-spon-si-bil-i-ties`:

```
^((?:[^-]+?-?){8})(-.+)$
```

- `^(` - start the capture group leading up to the half way point
- `(?:[^-]+?-?)` - find everything not a hyphen with an optional hyphen after it. Make the hyphen optional so that the second capture group can greedily claim it
- `{8}` - 8 times; this will get us half way
- `)` - close the half way capture group
- `(-.+)?$` - greedily get the hyphen and everything after it till the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple js approach based on string splitting. There could be a binary search style algorithm as you mentioned which would avoid the array allocation but that seems overkill for these small data sets.

```js
function halve(str) {
    var right = str.split('-');
    var left = right.splice(0, Math.ceil(right.length / 2));
    return right.length > 0 ? [left.join('-'), '-' + right.join('-')] : left;
}

console.log(halve('re-spon-si-bil-i-ties'));
console.log(halve('com-pe-ten-cies.'));
console.log(halve('ini-tia-tives.'));
console.log(halve('vul-ner-a-bil-i-ties'));
console.log(halve('none')); // no hyphens returns ["none"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work this out with this method:

- Get middle point of string
- From the middle point, and checking each character in both directions (left from middle, right from middle) check if that position is the `-` character. Set the index to the first such match.
- If it matches that character, stop the loop and split the string on that index, otherwise return the original word.

```js
words = [
  're-spon-si-bil-i-ties',
  'com-pe-ten-cies.',
  'ini-tia-tives.',
  'vul-ner-a-bil-i-ties',
  'test',
  '-aa',
  'aa-'
];

split = '-'

for(word of words) {
  m=Math.floor(word.length/2),offset=0,i=null
  do{
    if(word[m-offset] == split) i = m-offset
    else if(word[m+offset] == split) i = m+offset
    else offset++
  }while(offset<=m && i == null)
  if(i!=null && i>0) console.log([word.substring(0,i),word.substring(i)])
  else console.log(word)
}
```